# How popular does graphql get used in real project

Tags: graphql

All:

When I try to build a Reactjs shopping app, I find many posts mentioned one server side tech called GraphQL, so I go to FB website to learn its intro. I am so confused by its definition work of TYPE SCHEMA QUERY etcs, and build a data server seems take a lot of work to redesign how the data been fetched.

So my question is how practical this tech get used in real project and is it worth investing time to learn for my simple project(the main data REST requests are mostly products, users etcs)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is relatively new (released as "preview" only a year ago), but the trend towards widespread adoption is very clear. Among the early adopters are many startups, and Twitter among others. As I've written in a [blog post](https://medium.com/apollo-stack/why-graphql-is-the-future-3bec28193807), I think you'll be seeing much more of that.

If your project is relatively small and your REST API is simple, there many not be many benefits to using GraphQL, but if you're either building a larger app or working in a team, the benefits of GraphQL far outweigh the extra work you have to put in at the beginning.